# What does the command pkill -USR1 -n -x dd mean exactly?

Tags: kill, dd, signals

I am using `dd` to do a network transfer of a disk image to an sd card on my BeagleBone.

Using `pkill -USR1 -n -x dd` in an ssh connection to this BeagleBone gives me a status update of the transfer process, which is great.  I am just curious how it is actually working so I can use it effectively in the future.

After reading `man pkill` it still didn't totally explain how `pkill -USR1 -n -x dd` is working to give me this very useful status update.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is behavior specific to `dd`. From the `dd` man page:

> Sending  a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.
>
> ```
> $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
> $ kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 1; kill $pid
>
> 18335302+0 records in 18335302+0 records out 9387674624 bytes (9.4 GB) copied,  34.6279  seconds, 271 MB/s
> ```

`-USR1` tells `pkill` to send the `USR1` signal. `-n` and `-x` are just filters to make sure you send to the right process (`-n` sends to the newest process and `-x` means the process must be named exactly `dd`)

Comment: This is only in the GNU version of 'dd' (AFAIK). A SIGUSR1 to 'dd' for other OSes (eg AIX, HP-UX & Solaris)  will terminate the process, by default.

Comment: @DarkHeart use SIGINFO (or INFO) on osx (probably the same on bsd)